# Template class specialization with std::enable_if and a concrete type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I have `JsonFormatter` template class that is specialized for different types like arithmetic etc... in the following way:

```
template <class T, typename Enable = void>
class JsonFormatter;

template <class T>
class JsonFormatter<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
{
};
```

it is not clear how to specialize it for a concrete type like `std::string`, for example? My first idea was something like this:

```
template <>
class JsonFormatter<std::string, std::true_type>
{
};
```

but this does not compile. When I use

```
JsonFormatter<std::string>
```

I get

```
"undefined class 'JsonFormatter<std::string,void>'"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important point is that the specialization has to match the primary. In this case, the primary is set up such that the 2nd template parameter is going to be `void` - it's not intended to be provided by the user, it's just there to enable people to use `enable_if`.

`std::true_type` doesn't match `void`, which is why it doesn't work. When the user writes `JsonFormatter<std::string>`, the default argument will get instantiated as `void` - so they're looking for the specialization `JsonFormatter<std::string, void>`... which isn't what you provided.

You want:

```
template <>
class JsonFormatter<std::string, void>
{ };
```

Or even just:

```
template <>
class JsonFormatter<std::string>
{ };
```

Since the default argument will get filled in just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you specialize the template:

```
template <>
class JsonFormatter<std::string, void>
{
};
```

You can also use `std::enable_if`, but I don't recommend it since it a simple specialization is much easier. `std::enable_if` works correctly with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) only. So it needs to depend on a template parameter:

```
template <class T>
class JsonFormatter<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, std::string>>>
{
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> it is not clear how to specialize it for a concrete type like `std::string`, for example?

Have you tried simply with

```
template <>
class JsonFormatter<std::string>
{
};
```

?

Should works.

The second template parameter become `void` according the dafault value defined in the main version.